# Rename a div class

Tags: html, css, class

i have this div class in style

```
.page-banner{
background-image:url(../images/background-sec1.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

and I've tried to create a new div in the same style with the same declarations but with a new name .page-banner-**category**.

```
.page-banner-category{
background-image:url(../images/background-sec1.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

and ...

```
<div class="page-banner-category">
```

but it does not work,what am i missing here?

Comment: Just make it `page-banner-category` no `**`

Comment: Please post some code, it can not happen "just like that".

Comment: Give us a working demo that accurately reproduces the problem. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: Your code should work fine. Did you remember to close your `<div class="page-banner-category></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your HTML code as well to see how you use them? It is difficult to say right away what went wrong.

Also, in your CSS code you don't have to create 2 declarations, you can just use a multiple selector:

```
.page-banner, .page-banner-**category**{ 
background-image:url(../images/background-sec1.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

It will be easier down the road to update them when needed if behaviour is completely

Answer (score 0):

here is.

```
<div class="page-banner-category col-md-10">
            <?php echo single_cat_title('', false); ?>
        <div class="theme-breadcrumb">
            <?php niche_custom_breadcrumbs(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was published before, this is for PHP, and what I try to do is just change the image banner in X category.

Thanks for you reply.